# Attaching three cells from the same row that another cell is edited to an email using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an automatic notification system that will use VBA to send an email as soon as a specific cell is populated with a persons initials. This flags the rest of the team that another task has been created.

Here is the code I'm currently using, but I cannot figure out how to pinpoint the three cells from the active cell.

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim workrng As Range
Dim RNG As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)



Application.DisplayAlerts = True


strbody = "" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Please review the QPC" & vbNewLine & _
          "" & vbNewLine & _
          "" & vbNewLine & _
          ""

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With OutMail
    .To = "rschmucker@kessington.com;"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "QPC"
    .Body = "New entry on the QPC"
    'You can add a file like this
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .display   'or use .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I need the body to include cells A4, B4, C4 if cell H4 is populated with the correct initals.

The same goes for A5, B5, C5 when H5 is populated and so on down the list.

Comment: You'll need to use a `worksheet_change` event to trigger when certain cells are populated then add info to `strbody` (which you aren't currently using after you create it). How do you expect to check whether `H4` is populated with the correct initials? How do you intend to include the additional cells in the body of the email, just one cell value after another or in a formatted table?

Comment: Michael, the code listed above is a sub. It is only triggered to run when the active cell is populated with either "IS" or "CR." To your point about strbody, i was experimenting with different verbiage in the .body to try and see what would and wouldn't populate. I'm pretty new to VBA, so it's quite a bit of trial and error at this point. I appreciate it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your specific question of not being able to find the corresponding cells to the `ActiveCell`, you can use the [OFFSET property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) to reference them, or capture the reference by using the Activecell `Row` property.

```
'This will reference one cell to the left of your activecell
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Address & " is one cell to left"

'This will reference the cell column A on the same row of your ActiveCell
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Worksheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("A:A").Column).Address & " is the cell in the A column"


'This is how you would include Column a and b in your email separated by a return line.
    .body = ActiveCell.Worksheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("A:A").Column) & Chr(10) _
        & ActiveCell.Worksheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("B:B").Column)
```

Note that some of the above code is done intentionally illustrative. You could replace `Range("A:A").Column`  with `1` as well as not call the Worksheet property.

Comment: This works very well. I do have one issue with this code, however. It only works correctly with the tab function. if the enter key is used, it returns the information for the row below. is there a way to get in front of this? Thank you.